# window.open is having issue with firefox

Tags: javascript, python, html, firefox, jinja2

I am using `window.open` method to open a new webpage in myhtml. but when I am running it in Firefox it is reloading the same page. But it is working in Chrome and Safari. Here is my html and javascript snippet.I am using `Python Flask framework` with `Jinja` template. I also tried using `location.replace` instead of `window.open`

```
        </div>
        <form name="items">
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                function getdetails(name){
                    window.open("/details?name="+name,"_self")
                }
            </script>
            <table id="main" align="center" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> <strong> SNo </strong></th>
                    <th> <strong> name </strong></th>
                    <th> <strong> item </strong></th>
                    <th> <strong> Total numbers </strong></th>
                    <th> <strong> size </strong></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                {% set count = 1 %}
                <tbody id="tablebody">
                {% for i in rows %}
                    {% for name,values in i.iteritems() %}
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center"> {{ count }}</td>
                            <td> <a href=# id=link onclick="getdetails('{{ name }}');"> {{ name }} </a> </td>
                            {% for j in values %}
                                <td>  {{ j }}  </td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% set count = count + 1 %}
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: you want to open it as a new tab or new pop up window?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear, are you trying to open the content in new window or just a different page in the same window?

Comment: I need to open a new tab. no need to open popup window

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.location.href instead of window.open, location.href is a property and not a method so you'd have to call it differently, but it does work like a page redirect, although  i'd try to figure out whats going wrong with window.open - it is the more 'correct' way.

```
 window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Since your questions was a bit unclear, if you're trying to make the page open in a new tab, change _self to _blank in the window.open method.

```
 window.open("/details?name="+name,"_blank");
```

Comment: I want open in tab. i removed _self but no luck

Comment: don't remove _self - change it to "_blank" - firefox will open any other tag in that parameter in the main window... it must be "_blank" to create a new tab.